# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}^d)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}^d$ be the collection of sets that can be written as the finite union of half open rectangles $(a,b]^d$.

**Exercise:** Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}^d)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

**My Question:**

In the solution to this problem it is stated that it is enough to show that $\mathcal{F}^d\subseteq\mathcal B( \mathbb{R}^d)$.

Why is that true?

I know that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}^d)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{F}^d)$, but I don't see why $\mathcal{F}^d\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\Rightarrow \sigma(\mathcal{F}^d)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $B(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^d$. It's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: "enough to show $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathbb R^d$" must be "enough to show $\mathcal F^d\subseteq\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^d$

---

Let $\Omega$ be a set and let $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal A$ be subcollections of $\wp(\Omega)$.

It can be shown that the **intersection** of all $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega$ that contain $\mathcal V$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal V$.

It is denoted by $\sigma(\mathcal V)$.

So if $\mathcal V\subseteq\mathcal A$ where $\mathcal A$ denotes a $\sigma$-algebra then **by definition** $\sigma(\mathcal V)\subseteq\mathcal A$.

---

This can be applied on $\Omega=\mathbb R^d$, $\mathcal V=\mathcal F^d$ and $\mathcal A=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$